# Scala - Behaviour of hashCode & equals when using mutable HashSet

Tags: scala, functional-programming

CASE#1- I have the following class:

```
class Bear (val aName: String) { 
   def getName: String = aName
   override def equals (a : Any) : Boolean = { println("Test Equals"); true}      
 }
```

If I run the following code I get the results below:

```
import scala.collection.mutable.HashSet 
val bear1 = new Bear("Black") 
val bear2 = new Bear("Black") 
val setBears: HashSet[Bear] = HashSet (bear1,bear2) 
println(setBears) 

res: Set(scalaproj.Bear@7d4991ad, scalaproj.Bear@28d93b30)
```

CASE#2- However, when I add the hashCode method to the class

```
class Bear (val aName: String) { 
   def getName: String = aName
   override def equals (a : Any) : Boolean = { println("Test Equals"); true}      
   override def hashCode() = { println("Test Hash");100 }
 }
```

and run the same code I get the results below:

```
import scala.collection.mutable.HashSet 
val bear1 = new Bear("Black") 
val bear2 = new Bear("Black") 
val setBears: HashSet[Bear] = HashSet (bear1,bear2) 
println(setBears) 

res: Test Hash
     Test Hash
     Test Equals
     Test Hash
     Set(scalaproj.Bear@64)
```

My two questions:

1- CASE #2- Why is it that when the hashCode method is defined it is being called three times - twice when adding "bear1" and one time when adding "bear2"

2- CASE #1 - Why is it that the equals method is not called at all when the hashCode is not defined - eventhough it was called in CASE#2. (Even for a case class the overridden equals method is usually called in all cases)

Comment: The equals method doesn't have to be called if hash codes are different.

Comment: Rephrasing @Bubletan, different hashes ensure different objects. The first implementation always gives different hashes for different instances. Therefore equals is never invoked.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I guess you both have answered CASE#1.  Because the hashCode is not overridden (user defined) the default is used. This default hashCode returns different results for bear1 & bear2 in which case the equals method does not need to be called at all.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

*About question #2:*

When two objects have the same `hashCode`, the `equals` method will be called to settle the 'tie'. Because in this case the hash is different, equals will not be called

*About question #1:*

In reality what is happening is that when the `HashSet` is defined, the `hash` method for `bear1` and `bear2` are called, because they evaluate to the same value (namely 100), the `equals` will also be called.

The extra call to the `hashCode` method is because of the `println(setBears)`. It shows the hash for each object in the hashset.

So, when creating the HashSet, it adds up to two `hashCode` calls (one for each bear) and one `equals` call to settle the tie

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Yes I can see that because of the tie in the result of hashCode in CASE#2 then the equals method is called. Also, I can see that the println(setBears) is actually calling the hashCode method.